# Why is my CPU usage constantly at 100%?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

As soon as I start my PC and check Task Manager, I see the percentage of CPU usage at 100%. When I click on the Details tab, I see that idle process is at 93-99%. I know that the idle process runs when there isn't anything demanding working, but I think it's strange for the CPU to be constantly at 100% and full speed.

Also my computer sometimes randomly freezes and crashes... could it be related to the CPU usage?

Specs: (OS: Windows 10)

- Intel i5 2550k
- nVidia GTX 770
- Asrock P67 Pro3
- Corsair C750M

I have just installed the latest Geforce drivers, and I have no new drivers available for the CPU

Comment: Suggestion: Update Intel chipset drivers and the Nvidia graphics drivers and test again. Also check for and disable any unneeded startup programs.

Comment: How can I update the chipset drivers?

Comment: Use the Intel® Driver & Support Assistant.

Comment: It says I have no updates available

Comment: Was Windows installed by you? If so how did you installed it? UEFI or Legacy?

Comment: I had Windows 7 installed by a technician and then I upgraded to 10 myself

Comment: If so it's very likely to be a Legacy (BIOS) installation. Not recommended for Modern Windows or Linux. Always use UEFI mode in any UEFI machine. That alone can be the cause .

Comment: try using "process explorer" to see more details on which process is taking all that cpu time

Comment: What is total shown above the Task Manager header (Name, Status, (CPU), Memory). in my case it is normally 3-4% on w8.1-64bit.

Comment: Do rule out possibility of virus, run Windows Defender quick scan and malwarebytes scan. quick scan doesn't check all disks, all partitions, all files, by if there is some virus it has likely to have infected the files that get checked by quick scan, so that will suffice.

Comment: Nowadays Bit Coin related virus/ trojan/ malware are running a lot, but they gobble up net a lot and very fast. If there is abnormally high net usage also, then such a type of activity is likely. And such net use is not visible in Task Manager. Task manager shows 0 net use, but they keep on eating net in hiding.

Comment: @VSRawat, in the "Processes" tab, where all processes and their percentage are listed, I see 100% for CPU, about 35% both for memory and for disk. Quick scans show nothing malicious

Answer (score 1):

The "System Idle Process" doesn't mean that the CPU is permanently operating at 100% utilisation.

The idle process will mean (unless you have a malware infection masquerading as said process) that the CPU is effectively [being put to sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/1392423/how-does-a-computer-sleep-wait-without-using-all-of-its-processing-power/1392425#1392425) for that percentage of time.

It is almost certainly unrelated to crashes or freezes.